# should i upgrade from mysql to mysqli of PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

My website has a pretty big database (and growing) and i was wondering if it would make any difference performance wise if i would upgrade the code from php5 to php7 and from mysql to mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: It good if you want to upgrade your website code with latest php and mysqli. it not effect your website performance but it will increase security and

Comment: I highly recommend PDO just to get used to it for later use ect. if you need help with PDO or mysqli just go ahead and post other questions regarding it and im sure the community will be happy to help you out.

Comment: *primarily opinion-based 
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* That is entirely up to you. Both are supported by PHP 7 yet the key thing here is to use a prepared statement. Those different API's do have their différences and you need to read the manuals.

Comment: *"I'm posting the link but if it's against the rules, mods please remove it"* - The URL wasn't needed since there's nothing that could be of use for anyone really, so I removed it in an edit.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, if it wont affect performance i guess i will postpone it a bit longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some day you will! As mentioned in comments it depends. Feeling its the time? then yes, it can help.
But if you upgrade your PHP you have to move to Mysqli or PDO. Both are good enough but moving to Mysqli is easier and needs minor changes in your code.
Mysqli is pre-configured for MySQL but PDO supports other databases, Mysqli has both procedural(as mysql) & object-oriented(as PDO) interfaces.
You may also check PHP doc about choosing APIs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)